# Problems reading XML from Internet Explorer (9)

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, activexobject

I have the following code:

```
var Xhr, Message;

if(typeof window.XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
    Xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    Xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

Xhr.open('GET', 'response.php', false);
Xhr.onreadystatechange = getXML;
Xhr.send();

// Here is the problem.

var getXML = function()
{
    if(Xhr.status == 200 && Xhr.readyState == 4)
        Message = Xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Message')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        /* It gets the message on Chrome, but NOT IE. */
}
```

And this is my xml (php) file:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: text/xml');

    // Other stuff...

?>
<Output>
 <Message><?= $Message ?></Message>
</Output>
```

Internet explorer throws me the next error: "Cannot obtain the value of the property 'childNodes' the object is null or undefined".

The weird thing is that when I try to open a normal xml file (i.e response.xml) Internet Explorer gets the text correctly, What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Note that I putted the getXML function AFTER being assigned, it should go upside, but by the way, that is not the problem, I just created a quick example..

Comment: Does your code work if you move the variable 'Message' into the global scope and if you read the content after you stored the response into the variable?

Comment: Like I said, it is not the original code, it's just an example I made, the problem is not the variable itself, the problem is that IE doesn't want to get the data value from the responseXML variable, it throws me the error I wrote before, and when I read a normal xml file (not generated by php) it works with it.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the encoding? The IE reacts very sensitive with different encoding. Have you tried your code with IE8 and 7?